# Error in a SQL Join Query for a listing page

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application which has a listing page with search functions which lists the records that match the query. This application is working perfectly well with MySQL. But with same data on a Windows server and MS SQL. It is giving the following error (the query is included in the error).

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting the nvarchar value 'contract_i' to data type
>   int.

```
SELECT ctbl_contract_funding_info.*,
       ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.funding_manager,
       ctbl_contract_workflow.id        AS id1,
       ctbl_contract_workflow.family_id AS main_id,
       ctbl_contract_workflow.parent_type
FROM   ctbl_contract_workflow
       LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_info
              ON ctbl_contract_funding_info.contract_id =
                 ctbl_contract_workflow.id
       LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt
              ON ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id =
                 ctbl_contract_workflow.id
       LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_fin
              ON ctbl_contract_funding_fin.contract_id =
                 ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id
ORDER  BY ctbl_contract_workflow.id ASC
```

The table definitions are as below

/***** Object:  Table [dbo].[ctbl_contract_compliance_mgmt]    Script Date: 01/03/2017 14:58:54 *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_compliance_mgmt](
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [save_flag] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [contract_id] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [opening_meeting] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [closing_meeting] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [Procurement_rules] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [budget_variance] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [audit] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [end_use_equipment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [bank_interest] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [visibility_requiremnt] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [special_requiremet] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [donor_guide] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [donor_guide_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [special_requiremet_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [visibility_requiremnt_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [type_topic] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [type_scope] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [type_incident] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [identified_through] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [date_initital_report] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [incident_status] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [createdby] [int] NULL,
 [createddate] [datetime] NULL,
 [flag] [int] NULL,
 [updatedby] [int] NULL,
 [updatedtime] [datetime] NULL,
 [retention_period] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [sub-awarding-permitted] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [sub_awarding_permitted] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [reporting_language] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [currency_type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_procurement_rules] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_budget_variance] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_audit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_end_use_equipment] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_bank_interest] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_sub_awarding_permitted] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_visibility_requiremnt] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_retention_period] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_special_requiremet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [comments_donor_guide] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [special_provisions] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_compliance_mgmt] ADD  CONSTRAINT     [DF_ctbl_contract_compliance_mgmt_flag]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [flag]
GO
```

---

***** Object:  Table [dbo].[ctbl_contract_funding_fin]    Script Date: 01/03/2017 14:59:28 *****/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_funding_fin](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [save_flag] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [contract_id] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [funding_mechanism] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [expense_recovery] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [type_in_kind_donation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [type_financing_mechanis] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [funding_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [funding_ceiling_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [funding_ceiling_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [total_budget_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [total_budget_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [total_budget_exchange_rate_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [total_budget_exchange_rate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [modified_total_budget_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [modified_total_budget_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [modified_budget_exchange_rate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [modified_total_budget] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [obligated_amount] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [total_obligated_amount_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [total_obligated_amount_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [end_date_finance_period] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [desc_partial_obligated_amount] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [period_financed_partial_obligated_months] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [partial_obligated_amount_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [expenditure_latest_accounts_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [expenditure_latest_closed_accounts_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [balance_latest_closed_accounts_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [balance_latest_closed_accounts_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [payment_mechanism] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [periodicity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [payment_requested] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [payment_requested_date] [datetime] NULL,
 [payment_received_date] [datetime] NULL,
 [payment_requested_amount_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [payment_received_amount_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [recovery_cost] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [cost_recovery_cost_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [cost_recovery_cost_gbp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [direct_charge] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [percentage_total_budget] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [indirect_cost] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [percentage_direct_cost_currency] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [waiver_approver_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [waiver_approver] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [co_financing_requirements] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [co_financing_amount] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [co_financing_total_budget] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [co_financing_conditions] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [createdby] [int] NULL,
 [createddate] [datetime] NULL,
 [updatedby] [int] NULL,
 [updatedtime] [datetime] NULL,
 [flag] [int] NULL,
 [location] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [financed_period_date] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [type_financing_mechanis_others] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [periodicity_comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

/***** Object:  Table [dbo].[ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt]    Script Date: 01/03/2017 15:00:40 *****/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [save_flag] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [contract_id] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [funding_manager] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [programme_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [programme_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [programme_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [operations_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [operations_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [operations_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [international_operations_auth_app_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [international_operations_auth_app_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [international_operations_auth_app_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [project_accountant_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [project_accountant_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [project_accountant_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_compliance_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_compliance_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_compliance_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_lead_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_lead_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_lead_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [focal_point_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [focal_point_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [focal_point_responsibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [funding_officer] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_phone] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [donor_address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [external_funding_contact] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [external_funding_phone] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [external_funding_email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [external_funding_address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [createdby] [int] NULL,
 [createddate] [datetime] NULL,
 [flag] [int] NULL,
 [updatedby] [int] NULL,
 [updatedtime] [datetime] NULL,
 [sub-awarding-permitted] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_programme_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_programme_position] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_operations_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_operations_position] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [international_workflow_operations_auth_app_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [international_workflow_operations_auth_app_position] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_project_accountant_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_project_accountant_position] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_donor_compliance_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_donor_compliance_position] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [workflow_donor_compliance_name_extra] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [workflow_donor_compliance_position_extra] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [workflow_signatory_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [workflow_signatory_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [workflow_msi_support_office_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [workflow_msi_support_office_position] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt] ADD  CONSTRAINT         [DF_ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt_flag]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [flag]
```

### GO

/***** Object:  Table [dbo].[ctbl_contract_workflow]    Script Date: 01/03/2017 15:01:11 *****/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctbl_contract_workflow](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [record_id] [int] NULL,
 [save_flag] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [entry_id] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 [fundingstatus] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [project_code] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [fundingHierarchy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ContractStatus] [int] NULL,
 [OperationResponsible] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [createdby] [int] NULL,
 [createddate] [datetime] NULL,
 [updatedby] [int] NULL,
 [updatedtime] [datetime] NULL,
 [flag] [int] NULL,
 [parent_id] [int] NULL,
  [parent_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [family_id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Show us the table definitions. Also, there is no `contract_i` field in your query. I would make sure that the fields you are joining on, are all of the same data type.

Comment: Comment out parts until you get rid of the error or look into your data types. The error itself should be quite clear.

Comment: Seems like that column contains at least one non-numeric value.

Comment: The problem with assuming that everything is well formed because it "works" with `MySQL` is that MySQL will do just about anything to allow it to produce a result set rather than generating an error. E.g. `select 1 + 'rubbish';` will return the result `1` rather than maybe, just maybe, pointing out that it cannot make any sane conversion of that string to an integer - whereas SQL Server will return exactly the same type of error you're talking about here.

Comment: @hage that's what I don't understand. There is no contract_i column in the query. The table definitions are as below

Comment: It's not complaining about a `contract_i` *column*, it's complaining about a `contract_i` *value*. *Which* column contains that value in one (or more) of its rows, we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using my psychic abilities, one of the columns called `contract_id` is defined as `nvarchar(10)` and contains the value `'contract_i'`, because someone accidentally coded inserted/updated a row with the *literal* `"contract_id"` when they intended to update/insert with a *variable* called `contract_id` (eg may have left off the leading `$` when using PHP etc).

MySQL "converts" (coerces) text to numeric by converting all the leading numeric characters (if any) to a number, discarding the rest, eg

```
123abc -> 123
12ab34 -> 12
abc -> 0
```

So MySQL converted `'contract_i'` to `0`,  of course not matching anything, but not giving an error either.

Comment: Yes, there actually was a row with **contract_i** entered in the column _contract_id_